# How are dimension units on openFoam?

Tags: openfoam

When I open U for example, I find:

```
dimensions      [0 1 -1 0 0 0 0]
```

That means m/s

What are the other dimensions?

Comment: This is a question specific to OpenFOAM -- which you should ask on the OpenFOAM-specific mailing lists and forums because that's where the people who know this software hang out.

Comment: I know, but i was trying to use this stack to gather people that use openFoam here. Then we can create a CFD stack community and migrate those questions. I tried on arena51 to create CFD stack but it didnt have enough visibility. @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth , to sum up, You are right. As you said people that know this software are not here. So i was thinking about to ask and answer myself many questions to bring them here.

Comment: I don't think posting fake questions and then answering yourself is an approved strategy. The thing really is that if you can't find a critical mass of people answering questions on the OpenFOAM specific forums, then you're not going to find that critical mass anywhere else either.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth if software specific questions are not allowed in this stack, I remove my question. Those questions are not fake. I had them and I discovered the answer. I like stack, they are more organized than most software foruns.

Comment: The question was already closed, so the point is moot. But what I'm saying is that you seem to want to create a forum where people can post their OpenFOAM-related questions. The thing is that that only makes sense if they can actually *get answers there as well*. But just because you have answered a few of your own questions doesn't mean that there is a critical mass of OpenFOAM-experienced people here who can do that for other questions.

Answer (score 4):

Units on the brackets follow the figure:

[image]

Accordingly, [0 1 -1 0 0 0 0] = m/s